# Rendering a gradient in a UIBezierPath

Tags: core-graphics, uibezierpath

How does one render a gradient inside a UIBezierPath and is it possible to store this state together with the bezierPath for faster re-rendering in drawRect?

I currently render bezierPaths inside drawRect but I cannot add a gradient.

When I call this method `CGContextDrawLinearGradient (ctx, gradient, gradientStartPoint, gradientEndPoint, 0);` I dont have an endPoint.

I tried using the BezierPath.currentPoint but I dont get the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

This wrapper function renders a gradient inside a UIBezierPath (Swift 4):

```
func drawLinearGradient(inside path:UIBezierPath, start:CGPoint, end:CGPoint, colors:[UIColor])
{
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    ctx.saveGState()
    path.addClip() // use the path as the clipping region

    let cgColors = colors.map({ $0.cgColor })
    guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: cgColors as CFArray, locations: nil) 
        else { return }

    ctx.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: start, end: end, options: [])

    ctx.restoreGState() // remove the clipping region for future draw operations
}
```

You could change this to render any type of gradient or other drawing code after you've set the clipping region using `path.addClip()`.

And you could cache the `CGGradient` object to improve your chances of the graphics system speeding up future rendering passes.